# Does slipstream on a single engine aircraft create a slight difference in wing strut loads during TO and Climb Out?

Tags: wing

If right rudder is used to counter yaw caused by propellor slipstream that hits the fin, does that same slipstream try to lift the left wing and push down on the right wing? If so are the strut loads slightly out of balance during take-off and slower portion of climb out?

Comment: Yes this is happening, but it isn't a big deal because you level the wings and side loads (or differential loads) is in the limit.You see that on landing, one wheel touch before the other.

Comment: Touching down with one wheel first has nothing to do with this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, think it through - if you have such forces that create asymmetrical lift effects, this would result in a rolling moment.  If you have a rolling moment, you will be applying aileron to counteract the rolling tendency, and the aileron application will cancel any asymmetrical lift effects in stopping the roll.

So the answer is, if the airplane is in a symmetrical configuration, that is, ailerons neutral and wings straight, it's possible to have rolling moments present from slipstream effects near the wing roots that could induce a mild rolling tendency due to slight differences in local angle of attack.

Assuming it's enough to roll the airplane, if you didn't do anything, you would in theory measure slightly more tension on the upgoing wing's lift strut and slightly less tension on the downgoing wing's lift strut, while the rolling axis acceleration is present.

However, you're not going to let it roll, you're going to apply aileron to stop the roll, and this will cancel out any lift differential that was present, as far as the lift struts are concerned, because the aileron application to stop the roll has equalized the total lift of the left/right wings.

Answer (score 0):

The two solutions that  engineers came with :1engine is not not aligned with longitudinal axes, 2 one wing incidence angles is bigger than the other wing.